# Convert HTML to PDF using itextsharp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, pdf

when converting html to pdf using `itextsharp` the style iam applying with css for the web page is not working in the converted pdf.

here is my css code :

```
<style type="text/css">
       .cssformat
            {
                width:300px;
                height:200px;
                border:2px solid black;
                background-color:white; 
                border-top-left-radius:60px 90px; 
                border-bottom-right-radius:60px 90px;
        }                
        </style>
```

here is my html code :

```
      <div id="divpdf" runat="server">
        <table id="tid" runat="server">
        <tr>
        <td>
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="this is new way of pdf" CssClass="cssformat"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

The following is what i have tried with c# :

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60f, 80f, -2f, 35f);
        divpdf.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());   
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        hw1.Parse(new StringReader(sttt));
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
        sw.Close();
        sr.Close();
        hw.Close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled quite a bit to convert from HTML to PDF using iTextSharp and eventually gave up because I could not get a converted PDF that looked 100% the same as my HTML5/CSS3 page. So I'm giving you the alternative that eventually worked for me.

There is surprisingly very little options available when you are not prepared to pay for a commercial library. I had the same requirement from one of my clients(to convert from HTML to PDF) that did not want to pay for any third party tools, so I had to make a plan. This is what I did, not the best solution, but it got the job done

I downloaded the newest version of [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). Unfortunately the wkhtmltopdf tool did not display some of my google graphs embedded in my HTML when converting to PDF. So I used the wkhtmltoimage tool also included to convert to a PNG, which woked as expected and displayed all the graphs.
I then downloaded the newest version of [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and converted the PNG to PDF.
I automated this process using C#.

Unfortunately this is not the most elegant solution because you have to perform two conversions and do a bit of work to automate everything, but this is the best solution I could come up with that gave me the desired results and quality.

Of course there are lots of commercial software out there that will do a faster and better job.

Just a side note:

The web page that I had to convert was devloped in HTML5 and CSS3 using version 3 of bootstrap and it contained some google graphs and charts. Everything was converted without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example to convert HTML content containing the inline CSS Code.

```
public static class PdfCreator {

    public static string ConvertHtmlToPdf(string htmlContent, string fileNameWithoutExtension, string filePath, string cssContent = "") {
        if (!Directory.Exists(filePath)) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        }

    var fileNameWithPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileNameWithoutExtension + ".pdf");

    using(var stream = new FileStream(fileNameWithPath, FileMode.Create)) {
        using(var document = new Document()) {
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();

            // instantiate custom tag processor and add to `HtmlPipelineContext`.
            var tagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
            tagProcessorFactory.AddProcessor(new TableData(), new string[] {
                HTML.Tag.TD
            });
            var htmlPipelineContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlPipelineContext.SetTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);

            var pdfWriterPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlPipelineContext, pdfWriterPipeline);

            // get an ICssResolver and add the custom CSS
            var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
            cssResolver.AddCss(cssContent, "utf-8", true);
            var cssResolverPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(
            cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

            var worker = new XMLWorker(cssResolverPipeline, true);
            var parser = new XMLParser(worker);
            using(var stringReader = new StringReader(htmlContent)) {
                parser.Parse(stringReader);
            }
        }
    }
    return fileNameWithPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The output format of `<asp:Lable>` is "span", which is inline type of display. So change the display to block. Enjoy..