# C#: How to convert HTML5/CSS3 into PDF document?

Tags: c#, html, css, itext, devextreme

It's obvious from the title what I want to do. I know it is possible to convert html to PDF document using a very popular library [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). But what I acknowledged from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700201/convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp) is iTextSharp cannot render HTML5 and CSS3 styles correctly. Is there any free library to achieve this?

**Backgroud:**
I am using [DevExtreme](http://js.devexpress.com/Blogs/widget-for-export/#.VNsH-PmUemE) for report generation. It has supported chart export in PDF but my client wants some extra content in PDF apart from charts. It is not supported by DevExtreme, so I took decision to write my own custom PDF exporter.

There are some libraries available but I cannot rely them since I can't predict in advance what issues will it cause in production in future. Correct me if I am wrong, there is no API given by Microsoft for manipulating PDF files. We can create and manipulate excel and doc files using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll but I didn't find anything for PDF manipulation.

Please suggest me what options I have.

Hope this makes sense..!

Comment: if its a rendered html page there is wkhtmltopdf - although your question is offtopic for stack overflow

Comment: Why is that question off topic?

Comment: @user2225104 - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: He is not asking for book/tool etc. He is asking for a clever way to solve his problem. And on how he should write his converter application.

Comment: http://www.princexml.com/ Never tried it but maybe buying > writing yourself.

Comment: Hello! What extra content in PDF isn't supported by DevExtreme exporter?

Answer (score 0):

A few years back I was using iTextSharp to get our html manuals in xhtml/css/wiki to pdf. It was...painful and a lot of work. So, the first news is: You will need quite a few weeks (2,3,4 weeks, depending on the grade of perfection you want) of time if what you have is not only a few html pages.

If you only have a very limited amount of pages, the quickest and dirtiest way is to make screenshots from your rendered pages and add those images to the pdf. Not very high-tech but quickly done.

If your style sheets can be sacrificed and you do not care about the formatting of the content to be identical, you can convert your html5 pages to xhtml so you can load them as XmlDocuments. Then you simply create a program which does some mapping from xml elements, such as `<h1>MyTitle</h1>` to some section of code which creates a pdf entity using iTextSharp. Basically that was the way I did it in my case. I also did some mapping from css style classes to some specific pdf formatting, but not to the extreme.

Also worth trying is converters from html (or xml) to tex/latex. If you are lucky you find one which does a good enough job. Then you can use pdftex and get your pdf.

Also, it is possible that you can print your documents to an xps printer and then convert the xps to pdf. Or you simply convince your customer that xps is what they want.